# Why is kivy unable to import kivy_clock?

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html

```
import kivy

kivy.require('1.0.7')

from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.button import Button


class TestApp(App):

def build(self):
    # return a Button() as a root widget
    return Button(text='hello world')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

**according to the above codes i have the following error**

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\USER\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-05-09_45.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.1.10
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 22:39:24) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe"
[ERROR  ] [Clock       ] Unable to import kivy._clock. Have you perhaps forgotten to compile kivy? Kivy contains Cython code which needs to be compiled. A missing kivy._clock often indicates the Cython code has not been compiled. Please follow the installation instructions and make sure to compile Kivy
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/Hello world/pop.py", line 4, in <module>
     from kivy.app import App
   File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 319, in <module>
     from kivy.base import runTouchApp, stopTouchApp
   File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 26, in <module>
     from kivy.clock import Clock
   File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\clock.py", line 363, in <module>
     from kivy._clock import CyClockBase, ClockEvent, FreeClockEvent, \
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy._clock'
```

I think there is a problem with the kivy_clock and Cython.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because however you installed Kivy, you didn't compile it or install a precompiled version.

Did you follow the instructions as kivy.org?

Comment: yes i have followed all the instructions but still the same error

Comment: I am also facing same problem. Did you find the fix for it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the build apk runs perfectly & I found the fix to it in my scenario.

I installed jdk11-devel on found issue with jdk8-devel & did buildozer android clean and the issue occured.

**Fix:**
I simply removed all buildozer downlload|compiled|build using command `rm -rf .buildozer` at the building project path. Post it I again build using `buildozer -v android debug deploy run` & all build as success.
So the issue was wrong earlier packed - build modules | packages which needs to be removed.